# Como utilizar o módulo Time junto com o módulo Sys

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um problema ao usar o modulo time.sleep junto com o modulo sys.
Nao esta dando a pausa que coloco no time.sleep.

```
import random
import time
import sys


cores = {'fim': '\033[m', 'vermelho': '\033[31m', 'amarelo': 
'\033[33m', 'roxo': '\033[35m' }

print(20 * f'{cores["vermelho"]}-{cores["fim"]}{cores["amarelo"]}= 
{cores["fim"]}{cores["vermelho"]}-{cores["fim"]}', 
f'{cores["roxo"]}JOKEMPO!!!{cores["fim"]}', 20 * 
f'{cores["vermelho"]}-{cores["fim"]}{cores["amarelo"]}={cores["fim"]} 
{cores["vermelho"]}-{cores["fim"]}' )
print('')

escolha = int(input('''Escolha:

[1] - Pedra 
[2] - Papel
[3] - Tesoura

 '''))
 print('')

 sys.stdout.write(f'{cores["vermelho"]}JO{cores["fim"]}')
 time.sleep(1)

 sys.stdout.write(f'  {cores["amarelo"]}KEM{cores["fim"]}')
 time.sleep(1)

 sys.stdout.write(f'  {cores["vermelho"]}POW!!!{cores["fim"]}')
 time.sleep(1)

 print('')
 print('')

escolha_pc = random.randint(1, 3)

if escolha == escolha_pc:
  print('Sua escolha foi igual a do PC, vocês empataram!!!')
elif escolha == 1 and escolha_pc == 2:
  print('Você escolheu Pedra e o PC Papel. Papel ganha da Pedra, o PC 
  ganhou!!!')
elif escolha == 1 and escolha_pc == 3:
  print('Você escolheu Pedra e o PC Tesoura. Pedra ganha de Tesoura, 
  você ganhou!!!')
elif escolha == 2 and escolha_pc == 1:
  print('Você escolheu Papel e o PC Pedra. Papel ganha da Pedra, você 
ganhou!!!')
elif escolha == 2 and escolha_pc == 3:
  print('Você escolheu Papel e o PC Tesoura. Papel perde para Tesoura, 
o PC ganho!!!')
elif escolha == 3 and escolha_pc == 1:
  print('Você escolheu Tesoura e o PC Pedra. Tesoura perde para Pedra, 
  o PC ganhou!!!')
elif escolha == 3 and escolha_pc == 2:
  print('Você escolheu Tesoura e o PC Papel. Tesoura ganha de Papel, 
  você ganhou!!!')

print('')
print(22 * f'{cores["vermelho"]}-{cores["fim"]}{cores["amarelo"]}= 
{cores["fim"]}{cores["vermelho"]}-{cores["fim"]}', 
f'{cores["roxo"]}FIM{cores["fim"]}', 22 * f'{cores["vermelho"]}- 
{cores["fim"]}{cores["amarelo"]}={cores["fim"]}{cores["vermelho"]}- 
{cores["fim"]}')
```

Entre JO, KEM e POW, deveria ter uma pausa de 1s, mas nao tem. Usei o modulo Sys para que JO, KEM e POW ficassem lado a lado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de `sys.stdout.write`, use simplesmente o comando `print`, mas passe o parâmetro opcional `flush` com o valor de `True`.

Por exemplo:

```
print(f'{cores["vermelho"]}JO{cores["fim"]}', end='', flush=True)
time.sleep(1)
```

O motivo que você deve ter visto o uso de `sys.stdout.write` em algum outro lugar é que com o `print` antigo de Python 2, era a única forma de se evitar a mudança de linha, (ou no mínimo um espaço, se houvesse uma vírgula no final).

Em Python 3, com a função `print`, os parâmetros opcionais `sep`, `end`, `file`,  e `flush` permitem um controle completo da impressão, sem uma sintaxe especial.

Na verdade, o seu problema poderia ser resolvido sem uso do `print` - continuando com o `sys.stdout.write` - só precisaria após cada `write` chamar o método `flush` no arquivo - `sys.stdout.flush()` - mas o uso do `print` não só é mais curto, como já faz essa chamada internamente para você.

E por fim, não é diretamente relacionado com sua pergunta: descobri a pouco tempo como fazer os códigos de cores ANSI que você está usando funcionarem também no Windows, sem precisar de configurações e instalações no sistema operacional - desta forma mais pessoas poderão usar seu código -

No windows, as pessoas devem instalar a biblioteca `colorama`, com o comando `pip install colorama`  -  e no começo do programa devem constar as linhas:

```
try:
    import colorama
    colorama.init()
except ImportError:
    pass
```